# Run OpenCL program on NVIDIA hardware

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, gpu

I've build a simple OpenCL based program (in C++) and tested in on Windows 8 system with AMD FirePro V4900 card. I was using AMD APP SDK.

When I copy my binaries to the other machine (Windows 8 with NVIDIA Quadro 4000 card) I get 
"The procedure entry point clReleaseDevice couldn't be located in the dynamic linked library (exe of my program)". This second machine has the latest NVIDIA drivers and CUDA 5 installed.

Any ideas on what to I need to make it work with NVIDIA hardware?

Comment: I don't believe this has anything to do with cuda so I'm removing that tag.

Comment: At a minimum, I would 1) check the NVidia OpenCL developer site, 2) download the NVidia SDK, and 3) make sure all necessary NVidia .dll's are installed from the SDK to your target machine: https://developer.nvidia.com/opencl.  AMD seems to be getting sloppy about their support for NVidia hardware lately :)

Comment: Why should AMD support NVidia hardware? It's NVidia's responsibility to implement the OpenCL spec properly for its own hardware, and as far as I know the NVidia OpenCL implementation is a thin wrapper which is converted to CUDA code under the hood, so it should mostly work. My guess is you are using an OpenCL 1.1 implementation (clReleaseDevice exists only under OpenCL 1.2) so if NVidia does not support OpenCL 1.2, you are dead in the water.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, this looks like the issue in my case. I use latest AMD SDK, hence OpenCL 1.2 and the NVIDIA card I am trying to run on supports only OpenCL 1.1. Do you know how can I build for OpenCL 1.1?

Comment: The only solution I can think of is to rewrite the code without using 1.2 features (such as device fission, image arrays, ...) which may or may not be workable depending on your application. NVidia OpenCL support has always been lackadaisical, not much you can do about it until they get around to it, sadly. You could rewrite the thing in CUDA, but then you lose the ability to run it under AMD hardware. Basically, competing niche standards are the suck.

Answer (score 2):

Its  an OpenCL 1.1 vs 1.2  version issue. Nvidia are STILL on  OpenCL version  1.1. You have used AMD's OpenCL 1.2.   To get and OpenCL app that works on both systems  need to remove your clReleaseDevice API call  and other  1.2 calls and recompile using the AMD SDK with the 1.1 version option.